# How Do I Include References in an ASP.NET web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

How Do I Include References in an ASP.NET web site?

In a typical C# program, when you want to include a name space, it is fairly easy to inculde the reference in the Visual Studio project.

I am trying to rebuild a asp.net C# web site from scratch  -- that is modeled after an already existing asp.net C# web site.  In the preexisting project, the .aspx files have tags such as " components probably do not need any special declaration and the project will run fine immediately after construction.  I also  unserstand what the "tel" tags are for (it is for a plug-in that is part of a third party compoenent that actually adds content to Visual Studio so that I can create a new project of that type).

But the "sue" referrs to a dll that is proprietory to where I work.  I need to include that DLL (and/or pdb file) in a new project.  How do I do this?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand but...Project -> Add Reference -> browse for the DLL??

Comment: Could you convert the website into a web application?

Answer (score 4):

VISUAL STUDIO 2012

- Right click on `references` in the solution explorer => click `add reference` to enter `the reference manager`
  then browse for your dll file.
- also you can add public third party packages to your project from `Project / Manage Nuget Packages`

VISUAL STUDIO 2010 & 2008

- Project => Add Reference (to open the reference manager), then browse for the DLL

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check if you have a **ASP.NET WebSite** or a **Asp.net WebApplication**.

If it is a ASP.NET WebSite :
   In Solution Explorer Window, you can right click WebSite --> Add reference

If it is a Web Application :
  So you can also right click Website-->Add reference **or** right click in References --> Add reference.